# Set value attribute in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set `value` attribute in HTML when it gets changed. 
I need this because I export HTML code for importing it later. 
I tried the following code:

```html
<input onchange="this.value = value" />
```

And would like to have the following code so `value` gets auto-filled after import:

```html
<input onchange="this.value = value" value="some-value" />
```

There is lots of lines like above but whatever I tried `value` just doesn't get set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the attribute to update, you got to set the attribute.

```html
<input onchange="this.setAttribute('value', value)" />
```

Comment: oh, this works awesomely! i suspect that there should be some simple solution like this. thanks a lot! will mark as accepted in 5 min stackoverflow timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can add this JavaScript code and omit the `onchange` HTML attribute:

```js
document.addEventListener("input", e => e.target.setAttribute('value', e.target.value));
```

```html
<input>
```

Notes:

- the `input` event triggers with every change, not just when the value is "entered".
- this works for all input elements on the page, including `textarea` and `select` elements.